# Nowadays do wine makers use squeeze-by-feet method for grape juice extraction to make wine?

Tags: wine

Nowadays do grapes squeezed/stomped for juice extraction like Adriano Celentano did it in the "The Taming of the Scoundrel" movie? Do some wine-makers still use such method of juice extraction for their exported wines?

Personally, I think stomping is not hygienic. But I'm afraid that some wine-makers still use such methods with respect to traditions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very few people stomp grapes anymore for commercial winemaking. There are some wineries that still do it, I've heard of several in burgundy. Maybe some really old world stuff in Eastern Europe. The problem is that is super messy. Grapes are very sweet and when that juice dries on you, it is very sticky. Machines are much more efficient at crushing and pressing these days and don't cost a whole lot and last a lifetime. I can't name anyone off the top of my head. A quick google search didn't turn up anything either.

As for they hygienic part, grapes are full of bird poop, dead bugs, spider webs, dirt. I've found dead birds, bird nests, dead lizards, snakes, you name it in grapes and vineyards. So, dirty feet don't really have much on all this dirty natural stuff. It's all moot anyways because the alcohol level in wine is high enough to kill any pathogen that makes it way on the grapes. So, you are safe from that standpoint.

Comment: Where is your data for pathogens and alcohol levels?  However, good answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have lived in the Provence for a year and currently live on an Spanish island. In both of those locations wine making is one of the most prominent activities, plus those locations are old world and full of character but nowhere have I ever seen grapes being crushed my feet. Only in the movies. In fact in France and in Spain you find 100 year old bodegas where you can see the old wine presses on display.